# JS - Problema a la hora de traspasar parametros a un href="javascript:funcion()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Este es mi codigo:

```
    "fnCreatedRow": function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ){    
        var nombre = aData.parametro['nombre'];
        var valor = aData.parametro['valor'];
        $('td:eq(2)',nRow).html('<a href="javascript:editarParametro('+nombre+','+valor+')"><i class="icono-editar" title="Editar"></i></a>');
    },
```

Estoy usando dataTables en un archivo js asociado a uno jsp.

Cuando se clica en ese icono que se aprecia en el codigo, se arranca esta funcion:

```
function editarParametro(nombre, valor){
    //abrir pop-up
    abrirModalAltaParameter();
    $('#tituloAltaLinkParameter').text("Editar parámetro");
    $('input#nombreParametro').val(nombre);
    $('input#valorParametro').val(valor);
}
```

Mi problema es que si las variables nombre y valor, son numeros, todo funciona, pero si son strings, no soy capaz de hacer arrancar la funcion, y me da este error:

VM111:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: PARAM1 is not defined
    at :1:17

Creo que tiene algo que ver con que si el contenido de las variables nombre y valor es un string, no se esta traspasando correctamente con el '+nombre+'.

Podriais ayudarme?. PD: la opción crear un onClick no me es posible porque mis tablas se crean dinámicamente y no se referenciarlas por su nombre al no ser fijo.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Solucionado. La linea asi funcionó:

$('td:eq(2)',nRow).html('');

Un saludo

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que los valores de `nombre` y `valor` sean `PARAM1` y `PARAM2`, respectivamente;  el `string` quedaría

```
'<a href="javascript:editarParametro(PARAM1, PARAM2)">...</a>
```

Es decir, se llamaría a la función `editarParámetro` pasando por argumento dos supuestas variables llamadas `PARAM1` y `PARAM2`, las cuales no existen.

Lo que realmente quieres conseguir es que se pase el valor `PARAM1` y `PARAM2` como `string`, de modo que necesitas poner comillas entre esos valores.

```
"fnCreatedRow": function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {    
  var nombre = aData.parametro['nombre'];
  var valor = aData.parametro['valor'];

  // Uso templated string para poder poner el caracter ' (single quote)
  // además de ganar legilibilidad
  $('td:eq(2)', nRow).html(`
    <a href="javascript:editarParametro('${nombre}','${valor}')">
      <i class="icono-editar" title="Editar"></i>
    </a>`);
},
// ...
```

Espero que sirva.